# How to make arcs loop around a circle a certain amount of time?

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to make a twirl that looks like this
. But can't properly draw the arc around the circle.

This is my image right now:
[A twirl that I'm trying to use to draw arcs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8V6.png)

Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

public class BlackHole extends Canvas {

public int subsection;

public int ar;
public int angle;

public BlackHole() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public void setsizecircle(int ar) {
    this.ar= ar;
}

public void setsubsection(int subsection) {
    this.subsection = subsection;
}

public void setangle(int angle) {
    this.angle = angle;
}

public void paint(Graphics window) {
    window.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    window.drawString("Big Black Hole", 50, 50);

    int width = 783;
    int height = 561;

    int centerx = width / 2;
    int centery = height / 2;

    int twirl = 20;
    int somedegree = 360/twirl;
    this.setangle(somedegree);

    double degreetoradian = (double) (angle * (Math.PI) / 180);
    int pointofintx = (int) (centerx + height * Math.cos(-degreetoradian));
    int pointofinty = (int) (centery + height * Math.sin(-degreetoradian));

    this.setsubsection(4);
    double widthsubsection = width / subsection;

    double heightsubsection = height / subsection;
    this.setsizecircle(90);

    window.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    window.fillOval(centerx - ar/ 2, centery - ar/ 2, ar, ar);

    for(int zz = 1; zz < 11; zz++){
    window.drawOval(centerx - (ar*zz / 2), centery - (ar*zz / 2), ar*zz, ar*zz);
    }
    for (int xy = 0; xy < twirl; xy++) {

    }
    for(int w = 0; w < 20; w++){
    //window.drawArc(centerx-275, centery, 600,600 , 0-(18*w), 90);
    }
    window.drawArc(centerx-275, centery, 600,600 , 0, 90);

    //System.out.println(partsubsection);
    //drawOval(int x1, int y1, int width, int height)
    window.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < subsection; i++) {
        window.drawLine(0, (int) heightsubsection * i, width, (int) heightsubsection * i);
    }

    window.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 561);
}
```

}

there are parts in it that I don't get. I can't make a twirl. StackOverflow is trying to restrict me from uploading all the codes, so this comment here is done to break it up.

Comment: Since I don't have enough rep, here is a picture of the twirl I need "https://previews.123rf.com/images/jiaking1/jiaking11504/jiaking1150400048/38962193-abstract-black-hole-on-twirl-checkerboard-vector-background-Stock-Vector.jpg".

Comment: We are going to need a minimum complete verifiable example or something for this. None of us are able to run that code for you if we have no idea what the variables are.

Comment: sorry. I'll post it out again.